# Where/conditional statement when using array_agg [SQL]

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to add a where statement to only return records where a transactions_id's in `transaction_id_2022` are not in `transaction_id_2021` column.

Sample table:

```
customer_id   transaction_id_2021           transaction_id_2022
382           ["81-a-39-b","22-t-42-f"]     ["81-a-39-b","22-t-42-f","93-g-64-t"]
742           ["53-y-11-g","43-t-55-a"]     ["53-y-11-g","43-t-55-a"]
```

Desired output table

```
customer_id   transaction_id_2021                       transaction_id_2022
382           ["81-a-39-b","22-t-42-f","29-f-31-i"]     ["81-a-39-b","22-t-42-f","93-g-64-t"]
```

Comment: "29-f-31-i" - where is this coming from in the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

the format should look like this:

```
SELECT col1
FROM your_table
WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT col2 FROM your_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of [`array_except`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_except) and [`cardinality`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#cardinality) should do the trick:

> `array_except(x, y)` → `array`
> Returns an array of elements in `x` but not in `y`, without duplicates.

> `cardinality(x)` → `bigint`
> Returns the cardinality (size) of the array `x`.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (customer_id, transaction_id_2021, transaction_id_2022) AS (
    VALUES (382, array['81-a-39-b','22-t-42-f'], array['81-a-39-b','22-t-42-f','93-g-64-t']),
        (742, array['53-y-11-g','43-t-55-a'], array['53-y-11-g','43-t-55-a'])
) 

-- query
select *
from dataset
where cardinality(array_except(transaction_id_2022, transaction_id_2021)) > 0
```

Output:

| customer_id | transaction_id_2021 | transaction_id_2022 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 382 | [81-a-39-b, 22-t-42-f] | [81-a-39-b, 22-t-42-f, 93-g-64-t] |